# Conditionally change values in a data frame to their column name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
set.seed(123)
test_data <- data.frame(id   = 1:6,
                        var1 = rbinom(n = 6, size = 1, prob = .5),
                        var2 = rbinom(n = 6, size = 1, prob = .5),
                        age  = sample(18:30, size = 6, replace = T))
```

I want to use `dplyr` or `purrr` to change the values that are equal to 1 in `var1` and `var2`, to the name of their column and keep the 0's the way they are.

The result would look like this.

```
id    var1  var2    age
1     0     var2    26
2     var1  var2    25
3     0     var2    19
4     var1  0       29
5     var1  var2    21
6     0     0       18
```

I have tried using `dplyr::mutate_at`

```
mutate_at(test_data,
          vars(var1, var2), 
          function(var_x) { ifelse(var_x == 1, colnames(var_x), var_x) })
```

This returns the following error. So, probably not the best way to go.

> Error in evalq(sys.calls(), ) : replacement has length
>   zero In addition: Warning message:   In rep(yes, length.out =
>   length(ans)) :   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

And I have tried using `purrr:map_at`

```
map_at(test_data, 
       c("var1", "var2"), 
       function(var_x) { ifelse(var_x == 1, colnames(var_x), var_x) })
```

And this returns this error.

> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test &
>   ok] :  replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message: In
>   rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be
>   NULL

While I'd prefer to work with `dplyr` or `purrr`, I'm open to suggestions using other approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`. The trick here is to `gather` first, replace the values and then `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)

test_data %>% 
  gather(var, val, -c(id, age)) %>% 
  mutate(val = ifelse(val == 1, var, val)) %>% 
  spread(var, val)

#  id age var1 var2
#1  1  26    0 var2
#2  2  25 var1 var2
#3  3  19    0 var2
#4  4  29 var1    0
#5  5  21 var1 var2
#6  6  18    0    0
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have to be too messy if you use an intermediate object:

```
ix <- which(test_data[2:3]==1,arr.ind=TRUE)
test_data[2:3][ix] <- names(test_data[2:3])[ix[,"col"]]

#  id var1 var2 age
#1  1    0 var2  26
#2  2 var1 var2  25
#3  3    0 var2  19
#4  4 var1    0  29
#5  5 var1 var2  21
#6  6    0    0  18
```

This should be relatively quick if you are dealing with big data as there is only one `<-` assignment operation to do the replacement. The overhead of making `ix` shouldn't be too large.

Answer (score 2):

And a few base R solutions :

```
# Solution 1
test_data[, 2:3] <- sapply(2:3, function(x) ifelse(test_data[x]==1, names(test_data[x]), 0))

# Solution 2
test_data[, c("var1", "var2")] <- sapply(c("var1", "var2"), function(x) ifelse(test_data[x]==1, x, 0))

# Solution 3 
for (i in 2:3) {test_data[,i] <- ifelse(test_data[,i] == 1, colnames(test_data[i]), 0)}

# Solution 4 - probably the most traightforward. Most of the job is vectorised
# works also for other values than 0 and 1
for (i in 2:3) {test_data[test_data[,i]==1,i] <- colnames(test_data[i])}

# etc...
```

Comment: Or with `Map` - `test_data[2:3] <- Map(function(x,y) replace(x,x==1,y), test_data[2:3], names(test_data[2:3]) )`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(test_data), id.var = c('id', 'age'))[, 
  value := as.character(value)
       ][value == 1, value := as.character(variable)],
               id + age ~variable, value.var = "value")
#   id age var1 var2
#1:  1  26    0 var2
#2:  2  25 var1 var2
#3:  3  19    0 var2
#4:  4  29 var1    0
#5:  5  21 var1 var2
#6:  6  18    0    0
```

Or an option suggested by @thelatemail

```
cols <- c("var1","var2")
test_data[, (cols) := Map(function(x,y) replace(x,x==1,y), .SD, cols), .SDcols=cols]
```

Or another option is `set` from `data.table`

```
setDT(test_data)
for(j in seq_along(cols)){
  set(test_data, i = NULL, j = cols[j], value = as.character(test_data[[cols[j]]]))
  set(test_data, i = which(test_data[[cols[j]]] == 1), j = cols[j], value = cols[j])
}
```

---

Or we can use `base R` methods

```
d1 <- `dim<-`(names(test_data)[2:3][col(test_data[, 2:3])], dim(test_data[, 2:3]))
d1[test_data[, 2:3]==0] <- 0
test_data[, 2:3] <- d1
```

Comment: Actually, I'm totally confused how I managed to do that replacement. Shouldn't `data.table` refuse to update the numeric columns to a character class?

Comment: @thelatemail  Thanks, I noticed that.  Not sure why it is not throwing an error with `Map` while it will show up with errors with `set` or the `melt/dcast`.  Is it because of the `replace` as `test_data[, var1 := replace(var1, var1==1, 'var1')];
 test_data
#   id var1 var2 age
#1:  1    0    1  26
#2:  2 var1    1  25`  My guess is that `replace` converts the column to `character` while in `set` etc. we are only replacing a part of the elements which is already an `integer`

Answer (score 0):

I would use these lines to do that, not sure, being an apprentice as I am, whether they are too clumsy:

```
test_data[test_data$var1==1,]$var1='var1'

test_data[test_data$var2==1,]$var2='var2'
```